# Реакция при запросе свойства

Tags: c#, .net

Есть объект типа dynamic, в который упакован некий `MyClass`. Если я к экземпляру (dynamic) обращаюсь и запрашиваю свойство Property1, например, то может ли сам экземпляр отловить это обращение, даже если этого свойства в нем нет, или запрос свойства при этом идет через тип?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Самый простой способ отлавливания обращений к членам класса — унаследоваться от [DynamicObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.dynamicobject.aspx).

Если вам достаточно словаря, ключи которого ведут себя как свойства, то есть ещё [ExpandoObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject.aspx).